# Windows rename multiple files from multiple folders having pattern

Tags: windows, command-line, script, rename, batch-rename

I have a folder in which there are multiple sub-folders(only one level) which has multiple files.
Names have some dynamic prefix that I want to remove based on pattern in it.

```
1. constant_1234_5382_0_file_name.txt      --> file_name.txt
2. constant_1234_5382_1_file-name.xls      --> file-name.xls
3. constant_12324_58382_20_file-name.pdf   --> file-name.pdf
```

If you can see the pattern is remove all prefix till 4th "_", I came up with something like below since i am new to Windows scripting.

```
rename "*_*_*_*_*" "/////////*.txt"
```

The problem with the above command is I have to know the exact length of prefix and add equal number of `/` in it.
I can do this for 1 folder by running it multiple times with some changes but I have to run this for 500+ folder which is not possible or quite hectic task where things can go wrong.

I tried the windows help for rename is not helpful and on google every other result was having some kind of constant prefix or length that was to be updated and that was not helping in my came since I need to trim all the values till 4th "`_`" irrespective of content between them from multiple folders.
Note:file may have extra underscores which we have to keep as is.

Answer (score 1):

```all-file-bat
@echo off 

for /r %%i in (*_*.*)do for /f tokens^=5*delims^=_ %%I in ('echo\%%~i')do ( 
    if "%%~J"=="" (set "_target=%%~I") else set "_target=%%~I_%%~J"
    %ComSpec% /v:on /s /c "rename "%%~i" "!_target!""
    )
```

---

1. List your files recursively and use them to get the path/name for the `rename` command:

```all-file-bat
for /r %%i in (*_*.*)do ...
    ...
    %ComSpec% /v:on /s /c "rename "%%~i" "!_target!""
```

2. Use `tokens^=5` + all (`*`) in one 2nd `for` loop to define target name:

```all-file-bat
for /r %%i ... for /f tokens^=5*delims^=_ %%I in ('echo\%%~i')do (
    ... (set "_target=%%~I") else set "_target=%%~I_%%~J"
    %ComSpec% /v:on /s /c "rename "%%~i" "!_target!""
    )
```

3. Use an `if` to check if you have any more strings after the fifth delimiter (`%%~J`), and if so, return the delimiter by adding `_` + `%%~J` to the target name

```all-file-bat
if "%%~J"=="" (set "_target=%%~I") else set "_target=%%~I_%%~J"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[Ren | Rename](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**

  [√] **[`EnableDelayedExpansion` | Refer: `%ComSpec% /v:on`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**